# Spring Security login validation without login page refresh

Tags: jquery, spring, twitter-bootstrap, spring-security

I am using Thymeleaf for login form and i have a bootstrap modal which is opened from button click,if the credential is invalid I have shown a text from server :

```
<div th:if="${param.error}">
            Invalid username and password.
        </div>
        <div th:if="${param.logout}">
            You have been logged out.
        </div>
        <form th:action="@{/login}" method="post">
            <div><label> User Name : <input type="text" name="username"/> </label></div>
            <div><label> Password: <input type="password" name="password"/> </label></div>
            <div><input type="submit" value="Sign In"/></div>
        </form>
```

The error is shown but the modal is closed as the page is refreshed. How to show `"Invalid username and password"` without page refresh/redirect. I have implemented db based authentication based on Java configuration.

Comment: may be AJAX can help you with page refresh.

Comment: @Valath Can you provide a working sample?